# Signalr 2.2.0 Private Messaging

Tags: c#, signalr

i am searching for private messaging with SignalR 2.2.0 and there are examples for group chat , not for private chat. Does anyone suggest me an article and how can i do private chat project with using SignalR 2.2.0 and MVC 5. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably do such though the Hub:

```
public void SendPrivateMessage(string receiverId, string message)
{
   var to = ConnectedUsers.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ConnectionId == receiverId);
   var from = ConnectedUsers.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ConnectionId == Context.ConnectionId);

   if (to != null && from != null)
   {
       Clients.Client(receiverId).sendPrivateMessage(Context.ConnectionId, from.UserName, message);
       Clients.Caller.sendPrivateMessage(receiverId, from.UserName, message);
   }
}
```

There is also a ton of tutorials online, for example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/562023/Asp-Net-SignalR-Chat-Room

Comment: Yes i studied with this article but it includes an old version of signalr so i understand the logic algoritm but i could not do smt like this in my project cause i am new. Is there any other article with new version or smt else @janhartmann

Comment: Do i need exactly a list of connected users id? Can i use my registered user's ids from my db? I mean, the user will select a name and message will be send to the selected users id? @janhartmann

Comment: Depends if the registered user id is the same as the one in SignalR.

Comment: sorry what did you mean "same as the one in SignalR. " @janhartmann

Comment: I do not know what ID you have in your database, you can provide some code samples on what you are trying to achieve and maybe we can look at it. Other than that, I think you'll need to study more on how SignalR works in general and setup some simple chat room and work in private messaging afterwards. :-)

Comment: Thanks so much, i understand, i made some different group chat examples, but the private messaging is problem, i will keep looking, by the way the ID in my db is a random number that user gets when first registering. It is unique in my db, so i thuogth i can use it instead of connection id?? @janhartmann

Comment: That is not possible, the `ConnectionId` is a unique number for that connected user. You'll need to map that in database to connect it with your persistent user. E.g. "ConnectedUsers" table with columns `UserId` and `ConnectionId` remember to maintain it on disconnect as well.